# Problem on saving Spark dataframe into Azure Synapse due to PySpark timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-synapse

I'm trying to save a Dataframe into an Azure Synapse table and I'm getting the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 107096;Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid...

The issue is with a timestamp column in my dataframe which looks like this: `2011-01-27T06:48:04.000+0000`. However the target column in Synapse is of type **datatime2 with maxlenght 8**.

For that I have tried is

```
.withColumn("myTimestampColumn", to_timestamp(col("myTimestampColumn"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

but the format won't change.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

A few things to notice:

- Synapse will only accept the transaction if the dataframe column is timestamp, giving the target column is datetime2
- I'm working with spark 2.4.5

Comment: what do you mean "format won't change"? Can you do a `df.show()` and post output before and after `withColumn`? Also would be cleaner from code point of view to use a different alias for casted column instead of reusing the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If your datetime column in Spark has a standard format (like `2011-01-27T06:48:04.000+0000`), you can directly cast to a timestamp, which will result in a format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

```
df2 = df.withColumn("myTimestampColumn", col("myTimestampColumn").cast("timestamp"))
```

Then you can save `df2` to your table.